# keeps sneaking glances down her shift

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At the center of *The Witch* is the family's eldest daughter, a young woman named Thomasin (Anya Taylor-Joy), whose coming of age is even more fraught for taking place in a secluded wilderness with only her family around. Her mother seems to suspect her of being untrustworthy even before witches enter the story, and her younger brother **keeps sneaking glances down her shift**.

[Source](http://www.vox.com/2016/2/19/11059008/the-witch-review-scary)

I am not sure what the brother exactly does. Does it mean that he is attracted by his sister? Is not in the review a TYPO when "shirt" was mistakenly replaced by "shift"?

Comment: Shift is correct. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemise

Comment: I suppose thinking it's a typo is a good reading strategy; but then so is trying a dictionary or two before posting a question over a word meaning.

Comment: However, I didn't know this meaning of *shift* before you asked this question, and I can see how a language learner could think the word *shift* to be out of place here. It's not a common word when it means *chemise*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why her younger brother keeps *sneaking glances* as I've not seen the movie. But it's not unreasonable to assume that the younger brother is curious about his eldest sister's physical development *down her shift*. And beyond the *shift/shirt* question I'm not sure how on-topic this is.

*shift*

> 3.0 A woman’s straight, unwaisted dress.
>
> 3.1 A long, loose-fitting undergarment.

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shift))

See also Catija's [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemise) to *chemise/shift*.

Answer (score -2):

A *shift* is a sort of dress that is worn under the dress... sort of like negligee... so yes, the brother is looking at his sister with some sort of sexual curiosity.